# Literal parentheses in postgres query, pgadmin vs. psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, pgadmin

The following query takes out the parentheses from a string, i.e. it regex replaces them with nothing.  It works as expected when I test it in pgAdimin III (1.12), but when part of a python script using psycopg2, it does not replace the parentheses at all.

```
 SELECT
    regexp_replace(location.name, '\\(|\\)', '', 'g') AS host
 FROM
    location
```

I'm running python 2.7.1 with psycopg2 2.3.2 and my OS is SLES 11 SP1.

I expect that a postgres query run in pgAdmin would return the same exact results as one ran with psycopg2, or is that an incorrect assumption?  I can provide data if needed, but `location.name` is a string, e.g.

> (goat) 172.10.x.x -> /var/log/messages

**EDIT**: Python code:

```
cursor.execute("""
     SELECT
        regexp_replace(location.name, '\\(|\\)', '', 'g') AS host
     FROM
        location
""")
```

The parameterized arguments looks like the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parametrized arguments:

```
sql='SELECT regexp_replace(location, %s, %s, %s)  from foo'
cursor.execute(sql,[r'\(|\)','','g'])
```

For example:

```
import psycopg2
connection=psycopg2.connect(
    database=config.PGDB,
    host=config.HOST,
    password=config.PASS)
cursor=connection.cursor()
sql='CREATE TABLE foo (location varchar(40))'
cursor.execute(sql)
sql='INSERT INTO foo (location) VALUES (%s)'
cursor.execute(sql,['(goat) 172.10.x.x -> /var/log/messages'])
sql='SELECT * FROM foo'
cursor.execute(sql)
data=cursor.fetchall()
print(data)
# [('(goat) 172.10.x.x -> /var/log/messages',)]

sql='SELECT regexp_replace(location, %s, %s, %s) FROM foo'
cursor.execute(sql,[r'\(|\)','','g'])
data=cursor.fetchall()
print(data)
# [('goat 172.10.x.x -> /var/log/messages',)]
```